# How to change the System clock of a Linux machine by using Java?

Tags: java, linux

I know that by using the command in the terminal

`date --set="2011-12-07 01:20:15.962"`

you would actually be able to change the System clock, so I tried it in Java and came up with the following statement

`Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("date --set=\"2011-12-07 01:20:15.962\"");`

but it was not able to set the clock.

Do you have any idea guys how it may be able work?

**Premise**:
The machine is *Slackware*,
The privilege is *root* level

Comment: Why do you mean by **didn't work**? Do you have privileges to do that?

Comment: @MarounMaroun yes, I'm using *root*

Comment: 'It didn't work' is unacceptable as a problem description. What happened instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"date","--set","2011-12-07 01:20:15.962"});
```

The above statement worked like magic. @Howard Gou was right with "*Parameters should be separated from program name*"

The parts of the command statement should be passed by using a String array.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with this line of code:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("date --set=\"2011-12-07 01:20:15.962\"");
```

- You did not wait for the process to complete (see also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor())
- Parameters should be separated from program name, try this:

  "date", "-s", "2011-12-07 01:20:15.962"

Alternatively, invoke shell as the process, and pass in a line of code:

```
.exec("sh", "-c", "date --set=\"2011-12-07 01:20:15.962\"")
```

Comment: Gou should it be passed through a String array?

Comment: you're correct. my memory was wrong - `exec` accepts string array, not `string...`.